# How to fire Select event in OpenLayers only when adding a feature and not when removing a feature from the selection?

Tags: openlayers, select, interaction

So I have various Points (comments) across a map on a comments layer and I have a select interaction which is used to show a text popup when the comments point is selected. When I select a point once, it works as it is supposed to. However, if I click anywhere else on the map after that, the select event still gets fired when it is not supposed to since I have used filter for the select interaction to select only the comments layer. Any idea what is causing this problem?

```js
let select = new ol.interaction.Select({
    layers: [commentsLayer]
    style: commentsLayerStyle,
})

map.addInteraction(select);

select.on('select', function (e) {
    const comment = select.getFeatures().item(0).getProperties().comment
    if (comment) {
        const content = document.getElementById('popup-content')
        content.innerHTML = comment;
        commentOverlay.setPosition(e.mapBrowserEvent.coordinate);
    }
})
```

EDIT:

I have realized the issue. The on select event is getting fired for de-selection of features too (clicking outside of the filtered layer). So I need to figure out a way for the on select event to fire only when a feature is selected and not when it is deselected. Does it have anything to do with addCondition option of Select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

```js
select.getFeatures().on('add', e => {
    const feature = e.element
    const comment = feature.getProperties().comment
    if (comment) {
        $("#popup-content").text(comment)
        commentOverlay.setPosition(feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates());
    } else
        $("#comment-modal").css("display", "block")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `select.on()` the event agets registered to the map as Active.
There is method to [getActive](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_Select-Select.html#getActive) `getActive()` state on map base on that boolean value you have to setActive() [setActive](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_Select-Select.html#setActive) so that map interaction gets disabled once the action is complete. So it will get back to its normal state.

Comment: But I do not want the interaction to be disabled. I want the select interaction to only work with the filtered layer. I do not understand why is it getting fired on non filtered layers.

Comment: the answer given by hanjin lee below should work for your case. If not can you write a example working code on codepen or any where i can see it.

Answer (score 0):

How about checking a selected feature of the filter layer inside the callback function? if empty, just return false.